# Redmine OpenID conncet with Keycloak

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect, redmine, redmine-plugins

I have configured Redmine and Keycloak in two instances and I want to config Redmine authenictation via Keycloak using OpenID conncet.

Plugin installed - https://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_openid_connect
Follwoed tutorial - https://devopsku.be/setup/redmine-keycloak/

But each and evry time I tried, it gives error *Invalid parameter redirect URI* I have done exactly the tutorail said tried different methods also. But no luck yet. If anyone might help on this will be really greatfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the plugin parameter "OpenID Connect scopes (comma-separated)" specify the value "openid"

Comment: Really thank you. You're a life saviour. It works perfectly.